# Multiple Monitors with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, multiple-monitors

I've got 2 monitors, and most of the time I've got some reference material open on one screen, and Visual Studio on the other. To really get in the zone, though, I need my code to be the only thing I see. Does anyone know if it's possible to have multiple code windows in Visual Studio? So far the best I can do is put debugger output and the solution explorer on my left monitor, and the rest of VS on the right. I would love to have code on both windows, however.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you right click on the file tabs, there's an option for "New Vertical Tab group"  Just maximize across both monitors and put the divider on the monitor divide and I think that's what you're after.

Comment: Obviously you can't do this if your window is maximised, make sure you "restore" it and then drag it out to fill both monitors - just thought I would add before someone screams!

Comment: I'm going to try this using Ultramon, because I can't stand non-maximized windows.

Comment: Correct, I use Ultramon but there are many utilities to maximize across multiple screens.  Grid is also very handy if you want to give it a shot.

Comment: Windows users must use Ultramon!

Comment: When I have dual identical-sized screens, then the stretched Visual Studio + vertical tab group recommendation is great for production code on one side, and tests on the other. Also, diffing with 2 monitors (one on each side) is awesome!

Comment: There is a Windows utility program called Actual Window Manager (http://www.actualtools.com/) that will allow you to maximize windows across multiple monitors.  You can also set up program-specific settings to make certain programs always open that way by default.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this answer. Exactly what I was after. Also..., Ultramon is neither free, nor zero-cost.

Answer (score 5):

See also the ["Visual Studio and dual/multiple monitors: how do I get optimized use out of my monitors?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937/visual-studio-and-dualmultiple-monitors-how-do-i-get-optimized-use-out-of-my-mo) question.

Answer (score 2):

Though I use [StudioTools](http://www.exactmagic.com/products/studiotools/index.html) for other purposes, it has a "Tear off Editor" option, with which you can "tear off" the file to a window and resize the window. Find it quite helpful

Answer (score 1):

Instead of enlarging the VS2008 window to span the two monitors, you can display the 'Code Definition Window' on another monitor: just drag it outside the main window!  I find this very handy to avoid switching between code windows: it is very often that one is interested in the definition of the symbol under the cursor...

The same is true for other windows like the 'Class View', the 'Call Browser', etc.  You can choose to keep them grouped in the same group with tabs, or drag each of them separately (click on the label of the tab to start the drag).