# View .aspx page in separate design and source tabs in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

We have three options to view any .aspx page  in a tab

- Design
- Source
- Split

How can we view **Design** and **Source** in separate tabs for a any aspx page ?

Or if this is impossible!! can we use **split** option by Vertically splitting the **Design** and **Source** ? if later one is possible, I could stretch the view onto two monitors like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101745/multiple-monitors-with-visual-studio-2008/101753#101753) as suggested by Nick Craver.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to get what you want, [ScottGu made an excellent blog post describing how](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/30/enabling-vertical-split-view-in-vs-2008.aspx).

Short version:

**Options** -> **HTML Designer** -> **General** -> Check **Split Views Vertically**

Answer (score 1):

There's an option in Visual Studio to choose how you want to orientate the split. [Instructions and pictures here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/30/enabling-vertical-split-view-in-vs-2008.aspx). Quick instruction:

> To enable vertical split-view
>   orientation in VS 2008, select the
>   tools->options menu item and go to the
>   HTML Designer->General section.  Then
>   check the "Split views vertically"
>   checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Visual Studios 2017:

**Tools** -> **Options** -> **Web Forms Designer** -> **General** -> Check **Split Views Vertically**